# Data normalization for K-Means algorithm

Tags: cluster-analysis, normalization, k-means

I want clustered my data using K-Means algorithm for this my data should be normalized I don't know which method of normalization is better for this algorithm? (min-max or z-transformation or decimal or...)rapid miner normalized data with z-transformation method but how I can implementation min-max normalization with rapid miner ? or which tools and method better for normalized data? I should be check that my data need to normalization? How?

Answer (score 0):

The proper way of normalization depends on your **data**.

As a rule of thumb:

1. If all axes measure the same thing, normalization is probably harmful
2. If axes have different units and very different scale, normalization is absolutely necessary (otherwise, you are comparing apples and oranges).
3. If you know or assume that certain attributes are more important than others, consider **manual weighting** of attributes.

As for min-max or z-transformation: this depends on the distribution of the data. **If you have outliers, min-max does not work well**.